# Plotting shear and normal stress as a function of angle

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot the mechanics of a block, so I need the stress and normal stresses plotted against the angle for 0 degrees - 90 degrees. I have attempted to make variables for all of these and the correct equations for shear (τ) and normal (σ) stresses:

```
angle = Table[i++ 5, {i, 0, 18}]

σ = 
 Table[
   ((σx + σy)/2) + (((σx - σy)/2)*Cos[2 θ]) + τxy*Sin[2 θ], 
   {σx, 1}, {σy, 1}, {τxy, 1}, {θ, angle}]

Τ = -((σx - σy)/2*Sin[2*θ]) + τxy*Cos[2*θ]
```

My question is that within the two formulas, I have variables that I need to define and then plot based on the changing angle, but I'm not sure how to do that. Then, I want to make a list of the shear and normal to plot with the angle. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are wanting to do a coordinate transform of your 2D stress tensor, i.e. you are wanting to calculate the normal stress, $\sigma_{x_1}$, shear stress, $\tau_{x_1y_1}$, in a coordinate system rotated $\theta$ degrees with respect to a coordinate system with normal stresses, $\sigma_{x}$ and $\sigma_{y}$, and shear stress, $\tau_{xy}$. Why not just create functions which you can then plot directly?

```
σx1[σx_, σx_, τxy_,θ_]:=((σx + σy)/2) + (((σx - σy)/2)*Cos[2 θ]) + τxy*Sin[2θ];

τx1y1[σx_, σx_, τxy_,θ_]:=-((σx - σy)/2*Sin[2*θ]) + τxy*Cos[2*θ];
```

You can then plot both of these functions based on whatever stress tensor you have to start of with:

```
Plot[σx1[1, 0, 0, θ], {θ, 0, \[Pi]/2}, AxesLabel -> {θ, σx1}]

Plot[τx1y1[1, 0, 0, θ], {θ, 0, \[Pi]/2},AxesLabel -> {θ, τx1y1}]
```

[image: plot1]

[image: plot2]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was going for, I'm just not too familiar with syntax yet.